# quero escrever um loop for...of em que troca a primeira letra do dia, na array, para maiúscula

Tags: javascript

Tenho meu código, só nao sei como finaliza-lo...

```
const days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'];

for (day of days) {
console.log(day);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/how-do-i-make-the-first-letter-of-a-string-uppercase-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

Se quer só imprimir, pode usar `.toUpperCase()` e `.substr()`:

```js
const days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'];

for (day of days) {
   console.log(day[0].toUpperCase()+day.substr(1));
}
```

O `day[0].toUpperCase()` converte a primeira letra para maiúscula, e o `day.substr(1)` retorna o segundo caractere até o fim. Aí é só concatenar as duas coisas.

Comment: Oops, caí no misleading to título vs código apresentado originalmente. A resposta que eu removi se baseava no `susbstring()`, também poderia ser o `slice()`. Como seria o tratamento no caso do elemento ser uma empty string ou até mesmo um null?

Comment: Escrevemos basicamente a mesma coisa eu só trocaria o day[o] por `substring(0,1)` ou `substr(0,1)`. Não é o caso do array apresentado na pergunta, mas por se tratar de um array de string genérico, algum dos elementos pode ser vazio ou ""

Comment: Ah sim... aí era só fazer um IF: `if(day) console.log(day[0].toUpperCase()+day.substr(1));`

Comment: não, é a mesma coisa só o edita pro `substr(0,1)`  no lugar do `day[0]` porque não vai estourar erro no caso de um `["banana","","maçã"]`. Saca?

Comment: Não tem necessidade, a pergunta não aborda essa possibilidade.

Answer (score 1):

Outra forma interessante de chegar ao mesmo resultando é com [`toUpperCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) e [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice). O `slice` serve para obter o resto da string sem apanhar a primeira letra:

```js
const days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'];

for (day of days) {
  console.log(day[0].toUpperCase() + day.slice(1));
}
```

Curiosamente até consegue fazer com uma regex simples, que apanha a primeira letra e a substitui pela versão maiúscula à custa de `toUpperCase`:

```js
const days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'];

for (day of days) {
  console.log(day.replace(/\w/, letra => letra.toUpperCase()));
}
```

O `\w` da regex é o que apanha a primeira letra para a transformação.